# Does JavaScript support the is operator?

Tags: javascript

Does JS support the `is` operator? *(edit:)* ...and if so is it the same as `instanceof`?

```
var blob = new Blob();

if (blob is Blob) {
    console.log("Yes");
}
else {
    console.log("No");
}
```

**EDIT:**
The reason I'm asking even though I could test in the console is that

1. Nothing came up when I searched online or here on SO
2. it might have been added for ES5 or ES6 and I don't know how to enable that in the console to test
3. if it's not added maybe it's planned to be added in the future

Comment: What did your web search research turn up regarding operators?

Comment: Did you even try or research?

Comment: And did you try it?

Comment: 3 pages and no mention of `is`. Plenty of mentions of `in`. I can post my search results. Nothing in related either.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no 'is' operator. The 'instanceof' operator is essentially the same.

Comment: I usually see something in related. The last few days nothing. So I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Not hard to find documentation on all available operators

Comment: The reason I'm asking even though I could test in the console is that for 1, nothing came up for it, 2. it might have been added for ES5 or ES6 and I don't know how to enable that in the console, 3. if it's not added maybe it's planned to be added.

Comment: For future reference, I believe a correct search query for your question would have been something like *[javascript check if object is instance of class](https://www.google.hu/search?q=javascript+check+if+object+is+instance+of+class)*, using which the information you are looking for does show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just opened my developer console in chrome and tried a simple test:

```
> is
```

The result:

```
VM1002:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: is is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

So, no, JS does not implement `is` it is completely undefined, however `instanceof` does indeed have the *exact* same functionality.

In answer to your edit:

- **nothing came up when I searched for it online or here on SO**: this is because it is not something that has been implemented as `is`(as it is in python), but as `instanceof`, without knowing what you're searching for (*"check instance javascript"*) it may have been difficult to find.
- **it might have been added for ES5 or ES6 and I don't know how to enable that in the console to test**: to my knowledge, the browser console has everything available in the JS engine available to use, if it's not there, then it's not a thing rather than it being disabled, the best way to test this would probably be to try using an ES6 compliant browser.
- **if it's not added maybe it's planned to be added in the future**: given that it's already been implemented as the `instanceof` operator, it's *unlikely* that it would also be added as the `is` operator, as they would have the same functionality, again one needs to know that it already exists before knowing an answer to this. You can find a list of reserved words such as `instanceof` (including future reserved words and ones that were never added) [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)

Comment: I've updated my question to explain more why I asked this question when I could have opened the console.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts check edit, it may not provide everything you want but hopefully something.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, through the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) in JavaScript:

```
var blob = new Blob();

if (blob instanceof Blob) {
    console.log("Yes");
}
else {
    console.log("No");
}
```